# Does a $\kappa$-Kurepa tree imply we have a slim $\kappa$-Kurepa tree?

Tags: set-theory

Take a $\kappa$-Kurepa tree to be a tree with more than $\kappa$ branches, of height $\kappa$, each level having cardinality less than $\kappa$

A slim $\kappa$-Kurepa tree is the same but the cardinality of each level $\alpha<\kappa$ has cardinality $\leq|\alpha|$.

Is it true in general the existence of a $\kappa$-Kurepa tree implies a slim one exists?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: @clathratus: The question is one that is sufficiently advanced that your comment, although well-meaning, feels to me a bit out of touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $\kappa$ is a successor, then any $\kappa$-Kurepa tree is slim (or, at least, is slim above some level).

But the implication is not true in general. For example, if $\kappa$ is a strong limit, then the full binary tree of height $\kappa$ is a $\kappa$-Kurepa tree. But if $\kappa$ additionally has some compactness properties (for example, if it is measurable) then there cannot be any slim $\kappa$-Kurepa trees.

Comment: Can you explain why such compactness properties like $\kappa$ being measurable imply that such a tree can not exist?

Comment: @Cla It might be better to ask this as a separate question, but briefly, if $j$ is the ultrapower map with critical point $\kappa$, and $T$ is a $\kappa$-Kurepa tree, then $j(T)$ has more than $\kappa$ many (partial) branches $b$ that go up to level $\kappa$, and each of these branches survives to level $\kappa$ (because it is extended into the full branch $j(b)$). This means that the $\kappa$th level of $j(T)$ has size more than $\kappa$, so $j(T)$ and $T$ cannot be slim.